# Как обработать Open Graph теги?

Tags: reactjs, node.js

Подскажите, есть ли какая-то библиотека для обработки OG-тегов? У меня задача такая, сейчас у меня есть чат и если пользователь скажем отправит ссылку на Ютуб видео, то его нужно отобразить. В общем, как в мессенджерах хочу сделать. Можете пожалуйста так же показать примером)